# stop to_csv in pandas from printing in scientific notation

Tags: python, pandas, scientific-notation

- I am trying to write a python code which removes scientific notation from all the files in a folder and then saves them.
- The files are cash flow projections and sometimes are very large numbers which is why they are being shown in scientific notation.
- The files must be submitted to a data warehouse which will not accept scientific notation.

Below is my code.

```
import pandas as pd
import os

# Define functions to be used
def left(s, amount):
    return s[:amount]

def right(s, amount):
    return s[-amount:]

def no_mo_sci_notation(cell_in):
    E_index = cell_in.find('E')

    sci_pt_1 = float(left(cell_in, E_index))
    sci_pt_2 = int(right(cell_in, len(cell_in) - E_index - 2))

    cell_out = sci_pt_1 * 10 ** sci_pt_2

    return cell_out

# Pull in Cash Flow Files for Cleaning
folder_path = 'N:/ABC/ABC/ABC/Clean_Script/'
input_folder_path = folder_path + 'input/'
output_folder_path = folder_path + 'output/'

all_files = os.listdir(input_folder_path)
all_files.sort()

CA_files = [pd.read_csv(input_folder_path + file, index_col=False) for file in all_files]

# Get rid of any scientific notation
for CA_file in CA_files:
    for i in range(len(CA_files)):
        for j in range(len(CA_file.columns)):
            if str(CA_file.iloc[i, j]).find('E') != -1:
                no_mo_sci_notation(CA_file.iloc[i, j])

# Print new files
for CA_file, file in zip(CA_files, all_files):
    CA_file.to_csv(output_folder_path + file, index=False)
```

I have tried adding

```
CA_file.iloc[i, j] = str(CA_file.iloc[i, j])
```

and

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.5f}'.format
```

as well as some other "solutions" I have seen online, but nothing seems to work for me.
Can anyone help with this?

Comment: What type of files are your working with? Is the data truly saved as scientific notation in the file or is that how it is viewed in say excel. What does the data look like when you open the files in a text editor?

Comment: The files are .csvs. I am testing them by opening them in notepad. They come in  with the format 2.67E+23 then the script appears to properly convert out of scientific notation, but then prints as 2.67e+23